# Cloud9 C codes running failure

Tags: docker, makefile, cloud9

First, I running Cloud9 on Docker (using with linuxserver/cloud9) on Raspbian
and installed build-essential on Cloud9

When I tried to run C code (such as printing hello world), it says

> Compiling /code/first_c.c ...
>
> cc     first_c.c   -o first_c
>
> bash: line 6: node: command not found
>
> Process exited with code: 127

Should I install something more? or how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to run C code, you don't need node, but you have to first install gcc by opening a terminal and running:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install gcc
```

Then check that your runner is `C (simple)` **and that you have uncheck the icon `Run in debug mode`**.

If you want to run in debug mode you have to install node and gdb with:

```
sudo apt install nodejs gdb
```

== Update ==

P.S.: When gdb is not installed, C9 shows wrongly :

> "gdbserver" is not installed

This is a bug: corrected by this (yet) [non-merged PR](https://github.com/c9/core/pull/535).